# WPF Datagrid copy last row of grid to new row in grid (Devexpress)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, devexpress, devexpress-wpf

there is thing that I want to do but I stack as a dummy. Here is the steps;

1. When user hit the ctrl + D button on Datagrid
2. The **Last row** of **datagrid** values will copied to clippopard or somewhere (eg.CopyToClipboard func.)
3. From clipboard or something else to again it could be a function e.g. pastToclipboard or we can use InitNewRowEventArgs which it gave us access the **RowHandle** funciton

Here is code I done so far.

```
private void dtg_tabletrial_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
  if (e.Key == Key.D && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
        {  
          MessageBox.Show("You hit ctrl + D");
        }
 }

 private void dtg_view_InitNewRow(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.InitNewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        dtg_tabletrial.SetCellValue(e.RowHandle, "UserName", "emre");
        dtg_tabletrial.SetCellValue(e.RowHandle, "Surname", "newcompany");
        dtg_tabletrial.SetCellValue(e.RowHandle, "Address", "new addres");
        dtg_tabletrial.SetCellValue(e.RowHandle, "Phone", "new phone");   
    }
```

Comment: By “last row”, do you mean: the last object in the source collection; the last ‘visible’ row (according to filter criteria, not necessarily visible in the viewport); or the most recently selected row?

Comment: last visible row of the datagrid I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks again to Mike Strobel , but I also included another solution for that. I'm writing down here to someone who will need it.

*Peace*

```
 private void dtg_tabletrial_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.D && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
        {

            DataGridTrialTable ff = new DataGridTrialTable();
            ff.Address = dtgtrialTable.LastOrDefault().Address;
            ff.UserName = dtgtrialTable.LastOrDefault().UserName;
            ff.Phone = dtgtrialTable.LastOrDefault().Phone;
            ff.Surname = dtgtrialTable.LastOrDefault().Surname;

            dtgtrialTable.Add(ff);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that 'last row' means the last *visible* row as determined by the currently applied sorting and filtering (i.e., the row that would appear last when you scroll to the bottom, which may not be *in view* at the moment).

There's a couple ways to do this, but this one is the simplest (I think), and it doesn't require your backing row objects to be marked `[Serializable]`:

```
private void CopyLastRowToAnotherGrid()
{
    const int targetHandle = DataControlBase.NewItemRowHandle;

    GridControl source = /* your first grid */;
    GridControl target = /* your second grid */;

    if (source.VisibleRowCount < 1|| !target.IsValidRowHandle(targetHandle))
        return;

    var sourceHandle = source.GetRowHandleByVisibleIndex(source.VisibleRowCount - 1);

    // You can set ClipboardCopyMode in Xaml.  The point is, we want the
    // headers to be included so we can match the cells up in case the
    // user has reordered them.
    source.ClipboardCopyMode = ClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;

    source.CopyRowsToClipboard(new[] { sourceHandle });

    var clipboardData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

    var data = clipboardData?.GetData(DataFormats.Text) as string;
    if (data == null)
        return;

    var targetView = target.View as TableView;
    if (targetView == null)
        return;

    targetView.AddNewRow();

    var headersAndRows = data.Split('\n');
    var headers = headersAndRows[0].Split('\t');
    var columnValues = headersAndRows[1].Split('\t');
    var columnLookup = target.Columns.ToDictionary(o => o.HeaderCaption?.ToString());

    for (var i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
    {
        var header = headers[i];
        if (columnLookup.TryGetValue(header, out var column))
            target.SetCellValue(targetHandle, column, columnValues[i]);
    }

    // If you want to *move* the row, then uncomment this line to
    // delete the row from the first grid:
    //(source.View as TableView)?.DeleteRow(sourceHandle);
}
```

Comment: can I define target and source as the same datagrid ?

Comment: Yes, that should be absolutely fine.